# Смещённые тени на PageList(Пагинация)

Tags: css, веб-программирование, asp.net

У меня не получилось написать свой ***PageList*** для сайта, поэтому пришлось использовать *плагин* ***PageList***.

В итоге тени на пейджере(если я не ошибся с названием) смещаются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предполагаю, что идёт конфликт стилей плагина с моими.

Привожу код ниже.

***Style.css:***

```
/*Сетка*/

body{
    /*background-color: #ccc;*/
    background-image: url(/Content/images/ogon_fon_plamya_51781_2048x1152.jpg); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#wrapper{
    width: 1100px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #3f557f;
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#header img{
   width: 100%;
}

#content{
    width: 80%;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0 10%;
}

#nav{
    width: 200px;
    height: 677px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;

}

#logo{
    width: 100%;
}

#nav ul{
    height: 515px;
    border: 0px solid CornflowerBlue;
    border-radius: 25%;
}

#map{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 223px;
}

#map img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px solid #FA8072;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#main{
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

#footer{
    width: 80%;
    height: 37px;
    margin: 0 10%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    clear: both;
}

#nav ul, .main_title, #footer, .small_card, .small_card1, .page_counter, .big_card{
    background-color: white;
}

/*Навигация*/
ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul li{
    list-style: none;
}

ul li:nth-child(n+2){
    padding: 20px;
}

ul li:nth-child(n+2):hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

/*Ссылки*/
a, a:visited{
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

table a{
    padding-left: 27px;
    width: auto;
    background-image: url(/Content/images/knopki_servis_03.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px;
    background-size: 17px 17px;
}

/*Текст*/
*{
    font-family: "Trebushet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1{
    padding-left: 20px;
}

h2{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

small{
    color: #d94e4b;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 60%;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#footer{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

p{
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

/*Таблицы*/
table{
    border-spacing: 20px;
}

.small_card{
    width: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #d94e4b;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.small_card content{
    padding: 20px;
}

.small_card img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #d94e4b;
}

.small_card1{
    width: 640px;
    border: 3px solid #d94e4b;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.page_counter{
    width: 640px;
    border: 3px solid #d94e4b;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.small_card1 content{
    padding: 20px;
}

.small_card1 img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #d94e4b;
    border-right: 3px solid #d94e4b;
}

/*Формы*/
.big_card{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.big_card img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}

form{
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    float: right;
}

fieldset{
    border: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

legend{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

input, select{
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: #ececec;
    border-style: none;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.main_title{
    border: 0px solid CornflowerBlue;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

***PageList.css:***

```
.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination > li {
  display: inline;
}

.pagination > li > a,
.pagination > li > span {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.pagination > li:first-child > a,
.pagination > li:first-child > span {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination > li:last-child > a,
.pagination > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination > li > a:hover,
.pagination > li > span:hover,
.pagination > li > a:focus,
.pagination > li > span:focus {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.pagination > .active > a,
.pagination > .active > span,
.pagination > .active > a:hover,
.pagination > .active > span:hover,
.pagination > .active > a:focus,
.pagination > .active > span:focus {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #428bca;
}

.pagination > .disabled > span,
.pagination > .disabled > a,
.pagination > .disabled > a:hover,
.pagination > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999999;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #dddddd;
}

.pagination-lg > li > a,
.pagination-lg > li > span {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.pagination-lg > li:first-child > a,
.pagination-lg > li:first-child > span {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}

.pagination-lg > li:last-child > a,
.pagination-lg > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.pagination-sm > li > a,
.pagination-sm > li > span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.pagination-sm > li:first-child > a,
.pagination-sm > li:first-child > span {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.pagination-sm > li:last-child > a,
.pagination-sm > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.pager {
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.pager:after {
  clear: both;
}

.pager:before,
.pager:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}


.pager li {
  display: inline;
}

.pager li > a,
.pager li > span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.pager li > a:hover,
.pager li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.pager .next > a,
.pager .next > span {
  float: right;
}

.pager .previous > a,
.pager .previous > span {
  float: left;
}

.pager .disabled > a,
.pager .disabled > a:hover,
.pager .disabled > a:focus,
.pager .disabled > span {
  color: #999999;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

***Index.cshtml:***

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MyProject.Models.Worker>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@{

    Layout = "/Views/MasterView.cshtml";
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="main_title" colspan="3"><h1>Главная</h1></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td class="small_card">
                <img src="@item.PhotoLink" alt="@item.Name" />
                <div class="content">
                    <small>@item.Position</small>
                    <h2>@item.Name</h2>
                    <p>@item.Description</p>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("EmployeesPage", "Home", new { item_id=item.Id})" title="Личный профиль">Перейти</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
</table>

<div>
    <span class="page_counter">Страница @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) из @Model.PageCount</span>

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
</div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="big_card" colspan="3">
            <img src="/Content/images/lhpp440.jpg" alt="Форма" />
            <form action="/Home/Order" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Сообщить об инциденте</legend>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Введте ваше имя..." required /><br />
                    <input type="tel" name="Tel" placeholder="(xxx)-xxx-xx-xx" required pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" /><br />
                    <select name="street">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select><br />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Добавьте, html-код полученной страницы, т.к. cshtml-код не дает возможности воспроизвести что-либо.

Comment: @Kniham вы имеете ввиду мастер страницу?

Comment: Нет. Код, который отображается в браузере.